# To add one month to current date

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have to add one month to todays date and have to get date after 1 month.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Dim newDate as DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

`dateAfterMonth = dateAfterMonth.AddMonths(1)`
If you would add 1 month from now:
`dateAfterMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)`

Answer (score 3):

Try [DateTime.AddMonths Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

using Fluent DateTime http://fluentdatetime.codeplex.com/

```
       Dim newDate as DateTime = 1.Months().FromNow()
```