# DateAdd in ms access Sql select in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I would like to find a way of outputting data from a ms access and adding 2 months before the data is shown to the end user
Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To add one month to current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382823/to-add-one-month-to-current-date)

Comment: No i was wondering if it was possible to do this in the SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dateadd can be used inside of an MS Access query.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, dateadd("m",2,Table1.dte) as NextDate
FROM Table1;
```